# Batch file to normalize audio using Mediainfo command line interface

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, mediainfo

I would like to create a Windows batch file script to normalize the audio for all videos (mostly .mkv files) in a folder.

I am using a python script called ffmpeg-normalize (utilizes ffmpeg's loudnorm filter 2pass) to accomplish this currently. This command line will currently normalize the audio (creates an output folder called "normalized") in all video files but I need to manually enter specific values for it to use the proper audio codec and sampling rate.

I would like to use Mediainfo command line interface to query each video file in the folder first and determine its audio bit depth and audio sampling rate and then use these values to assign the proper audio codec and sampling rate parameters to perform the loudness normalization on each file.

For example:

If the audio bit depth of the video file is 16 bits and the sampling rate is 44.1 khz then the command would be:

`for /f "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /b *.mkv') do ffmpeg-normalize -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 44100 "%G"`

If the audio bit depth of the video file is 24 bits and the sampling rate is 96.0 kHz then the command line would be:

`for /f "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /b *.mkv') do ffmpeg-normalize -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 96000 "%G"`

Audio bit depth of "16" should use pcm_s16le audio codec, Audio bit depth of "24" should use pcm_s24le audio codec, sampling rate of "44100: should use -ar 44100, etc

`mediainfo --Inform=Audio;%BitDepth% test.mkv` will generate the right bit depth (16 or 24)
`mediainfo --Inform=Audio;%SamplingRate% test.mkv` will generate the right sampling rate (44100,48000,88200,96000 or 192000)

Just dont know how to nest the FOR / TO DO / NEXT stuff in order to create the batch file.

Thank you in advance to anyone who is willing to assist.

Comment: I figured out a batch script to do this... I will post it soon for those interested. I just didn't want someone spending time writing code unnecessarily.